# populating combobox extjs in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, extjs, combobox

i have designed a form in extjs and exported proj to my rails appn..
soo 2 files that i am playing with is MyPanel.ui.js & MyPanel.js
i want to populate combobox with json store..
when i wrote below code :

```
{           xtype: 'combo',
            name:'username',
            id:'usercombo',
            ref:'usercombo',
            store:'RoleStore', autoShow:true,
            displayField:'username',
            valueField:'username',
            mode: 'local'
}
```

But when i write similar code in MyPanel.js, it does not work:

```
var combo1 = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
            store:'RoleStore', autoShow:true,
            displayField:'username',
            valueField:'username',
             mode: 'local',
              triggerAction: 'all',
              renderTo: 'usercombo'});`
```

I have followed link : http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/887318-how-populate-combobox-data-extjs-2-3-a

Comment: fyi - to make the code readable, always surround it with code tags or hit the curly brackets in the editor menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible issues I can see (you don't elaborate as to how it doesn't work):

1. `ref` in the original code has  been replaced with `renderTo`. [`ref`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Component.html#cfg-Ext.Component-ref) is used to set the current `Component` into the named property on a parent container. [`renderTo`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Component.html#cfg-Ext.Component-renderTo) is used to give the id of the DOM element, Ext element, etc, that the component is to be rendered to. If there's no element with an id of `usercombo` the second version will render into nothing.
2. `name` is missing from the second definition.

Answer (score 0):

Add `triggerAction:  'all',` to the combobox configuration

Comment: i tried adding triggerAction: 'all'it stilll does not work :(

Comment: Please put all (relevant) ext code here. (And use the editor to make it readable)

Comment: i got it working by writing code in xds_index.js..i followed this link : http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/form/combos.js